# How let babel-eslint support 'do' syntax in stage-1?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, eslint

I use stage-1 syntax 'do' in my react module, the compiled code will be running correctly, but eslint think 'do' syntax is error:

[image]

config code below:

```js
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "plugins": [
        "babel"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-expressions": 1
        // "semi": 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Disable eslint for this line/file. But better not to use use this kind of syntax from 0-stage, high chances that it won't be even accepted.

Comment: yeah, and i'm exhausted for looking solution for this, but 'do' expression is already on stage-1 :)

Comment: @Nokey which version of babel-eslint are you using? Try updating it to the latest version.

Comment: @Maluen babel-eslint: '^8.0.2', latest version, but is not working

Comment: Can you provide a minimal package.json + webpack config (if you're using it) + whatever is needed so that we can reproduce the issue?